# Strapi date format using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, date, strapi

I recieve this date format from strapi 2021-09-01T15:21:39.862Z
how can i transform it to a DD/MM/YYYY format ?

```
<div class="post-date-article">{{ formatMyDate(article.published_at) }}</div>

formatMyDate(value){
     if (value) {
       return value;
      }
  }
```

Comment: `let [y,m,d] = '2021-09-01T15:21:39.862Z'.split(/\D/); console.log(\`${d}/${m}/${y}\`);`

Comment: `'2021-09-01T15:21:39.862Z'.slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/')`

Answer (score 7):

Strapi are providing a date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is easy to parse using the JavaScript date object.

I'd suggest using [Date.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to format the input date
as `DD/MM/YYYY`. Using a locale of 'en-GB' will format the supplied date in this way.

You can pass other locales such as 'de-DE' to format the date in another way if you wish.

```js
function formatMyDate(value, locale = 'en-GB') {
    return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString(locale);
}

const timestamp = '2021-09-01T15:21:39.862Z';
console.log('Timestamp:', timestamp);
console.log('Formatted date:', formatMyDate(timestamp));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That also changes UTC to local, so for those with offset +9 or greater the date changes from 1 October to 2 October.

Comment: Good point @RobG, we can of course display in UTC if we wish using the timeZone option.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me with luxon

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
```

...

```
DateTime.now(post.attributes.createdAt).toFormat('MMMM dd, yyyy')}
```

or using date-fns (tree shakeable)

```
import { format, parseISO } from 'date-fns';
```

...

```
{format(parseISO(article.attributes.publishedAt), 'MMMM dd, yyyy')}
```